# Picture in body element: url issues?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a background image using CSS, but it doesn't seem to work. The CSS file is correctly linked to the HTML, because I can set the color of the `body` element to blue in CSS. Here's my code so far:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("assets/images/funky-line.png");
}
```

Comment: Share the file structure of your project as well.

Comment: urls inside css files are relative to the css file. So does the path point to the correct folder ?

Comment: This path assumes the `assets` folder is under the same directory as the css file.

Answer (score 0):

The path you specified means that the `assets` folder is under the same directory as the CSS file. I think the `assets` folder is under the root folder, isn't it? In that case, add a forward plash `/` to the beginning of the path:

```
background-image: url("/assets/images/funky-line.png");
```

Also, it is strange to define the size of the body like that. If you want to define the size of the background image and make it centered, replace these lines:

```
width: 960px;
height: 960px;
margin: auto;
```

With these:

```
background-size: 960px 960px;
background-position: center center; /* center top, to only center it horizontally */
```